# Hibernate filter-def/filter with a collection of enum as a parameter list is converted to VARBINARY

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

Hibernate:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2
Oracle: 11g
Java 1.7/1.8

Parent class ( see hbm config below) consists of a collection of Vehicle. Vehicle class a property VehicleType oft ype enum. Parent table has one-to-many relationship with Vehicle table.
The column Vehicle.vehicle_type is of type VARCHAR.

The issue occured on using a filer-def/filter to filter the Vehicles  by VehicleType (Collection by a Collection). With the config below the generated hibernate query did not yield any result.
I looked into the logs and verified the generated query. FYI. I rant he query in SQL developer and with expected params, it worked as expected.

Curious, I turned on the TRACE for  parameters, and found that hibernate was converting the enum  to VARBINARY, this seems to be the issue.

17:30:12,088 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - AUDI
17:30:12,088 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - PORSCHE

As a test, I passed a Collection contain the enum name to the filter parameter list, updated the filter-param type to string. This time, its the same query, but this time, the type was concverted to VARCHAR.

17:55:12,088 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - AUDI
17:55:12,088 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - PORSCHE

Regular Inserts work fine, VehicleType is converted to VARCHAR and persisted.

I expect Hibernate should be able to resolve and convert the enum value to VARCHAR as it did for the inserts or throw an exception if it cannot. It appears to be a bug.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.volks.cars"
                   default-access="field">

<class name="com.volks.cars.Parent"
           entity-name="Parent" >

 <list name="vehicles" inverse="false"
              cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" batch-size="90">
            <key column="cr_id" not-null="true"/>
            <list-index column="cr_idx"/>
            <one-to-many entity-name="Vehicle"/>
            <filter name="vechicleFilter" condition="vehicle_type in (:vechicleFilter)"/>
        </list>


         <filter-def name="vechicleFilter">
        <filter-param name="filterByVehicleType" type="com.volks.cars.enum.VehicleType"/>
    </filter-def>
</hibernate-mapping>



<hibernate-mapping package="com.volks.cars"
                   default-access="field">
    <class name="Vehicle"
           entity-name="Vehicle">
         <id name="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name="vehicleType" not-null="true">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">
                    com.volks.cars.enum.VehicleType
                </param>
                <param name="useNamed">true</param>
            </type>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


//Collection of VehicleType enum
Collection<VehicleType> vehicleTypes = new ArrayList<VehicleType>();
        vehicleTypes.add(VehicleType.ROOT_REFERENCE);
        vehicleTypes.add(VehicleType);

        //Setting the collection of enum as a parameter list in the filer.
        Filter filter = getCurrentSession().enableFilter("vechicleFilter");
        filter.setParameterList("vechicleFilter", vehicleTypes);




        public enum ChangeRequestReference {
        AUDI,
        PORSCHE,
        VOLKS
        }
```